# What does <+> mean?

Tags: c#, operators

I'm reading some documentation (under NDA) where is says to do the following operation:

```
Rnd1[11..7] <+> Rnd2[11..7]
```

`Rnd1` and `Rnd2` represent an array of bytes.

What should operator <+> do here?

I've browsed through entire documentation and can't find an explanation.

Comment: Could you link to that documentation and/or copy that fragment?

Comment: @HansKesting I wish I could, its under NDA so no.

Comment: That's almost certainly supposed to be an attempt at rendering an XOR symbol.  But without further context, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth From limited information I gave you think it just means to XOR bytes at same indexes?

Comment: None of that looks like C# to me... if that's meant to be documentation, it should explain what it's trying to achieve. There's really no point in us *guessing* what documentation means.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's not C#, they are writing in general for any programming language. I'm using C#.

Comment: All we can do is guess, if this is some kind of calculation and you know the result beforehand (out of some other service perhaps) then you can do some trial&error and compare.

Comment: @GillBates I wish I could write tests for this, but there are no examples given and values keep changing.

Comment: @ErikKralj: So you're asking what a general symbol means "for any programming language"? That doesn't make any sense, as each language determines its own meaning for symbols. We can't possibly know what is meant by `<+>` here. We could guess, but it would be nothing more *than* a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely an attempt to make an ASCII representation of the symbol ⊕, that symbol represents XOR.

So the documentation is likely telling you to take bytes 11 through 7 of `Rnd1` and xor them with the same bytes in `Rnd2`

```
public byte[] YourOperator(byte[] rnd1, byte[] rnd2)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[5];
    for(int i = 7; i <= 11; i++)
    {
         result[i - 7] = rnd1[i] ^ rnd2[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Be careful to check if the `7..11` is a inclusive or exclusive upper bound, that will change the number of bytes you are working with from a 5 to a 4 and the `<=` to a `<`.

The fact you signed a NDA to get the documentation means you should have working relationship with the company that gave it to you, the best option is to contact them and ask for clarification so you know for sure what they meant.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Linq way of doing things, e.g.

```
rnd1.Zip(rnd2, (r1, r2) => r1 ^ r2).Skip(7).Take(4);
```